# Как обнаружить цифры в строке умножить на 1000?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть у меня строка, в которой отображена перевернутая цена (может изменяться и расти с запасом до млрд) вида  `руб. 45`. Мне нужно с помощью скрипта поменять местами руб. и количество, причем умноженное на 1000, т.е. `45.000 руб.`
Перевернуть вот так `руб. 45` на `45 руб.` мне удалось

```
$val = value.replace(/^(.*?)(\d+)$/g,'$2 $1').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1.');
```

а вот умножить все никак не получается.

за что минусуете? что я сделал не так?

Comment: Вот [такой код](http://jsfiddle.net/3fvqwy51/) подойдёт?

Comment: @stribizhev а что означает в функции m, grp1, offset, input ?

Comment: m=всё совпадение, grp1=первая группа, offset=индекс совпадения в строке, input=вся входная строка.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var value = 'руб. 45';
var val = value.replace(/^(.*?) (\d+)$/g,  '$2000 $1');
alert(val);
```

Пример http://jsfiddle.net/w9atdccf/1/

**UPD**

Поправка http://jsfiddle.net/w9atdccf/4/

```
var value = 'руб. 45.000.000';
var val = value.replace(/^(.*?) (\d[\d\.]*)$/,  '$2.000 $1');
alert(val);
```

Comment: @Вася, если вам точка для разделения тысяч нужна, то так  http://jsfiddle.net/w9atdccf/2/ И флаг `g` по идее тут не нужен.

Comment: спасибо, только еще нужно учесть, что цена может быть `руб. 45.000` и `руб. 45.000.000`  о чем я писал выше, поэтому это решение сработает только для небольших порядков, а нужно, чтобы было универсоальное

Comment: @Вася, обновил.

Comment: вот теперь все супер! благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @Вася, еще раз обновил, чтобы точка в числе первой не могла быть.

Comment: упс.. возникла еще одна проблемка `руб.` закодировано в аски символах `&#440;&#443;&#431;.` вот для чего я использовал двойной `replace` блин..

Comment: @Вася, по примеру в моем ответе выводит `45.000.000.000 &#440;&#443;&#431;.` На странице думаю нормально отобразится.

Comment: @Вася, вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/w9atdccf/5/ У вас буквы как-то не так закодированы для UTF-8.

Comment: не, уже понял - там пробела оказывается не было `руб.45`. теперь вопрос окончательно снят. Еще раз спасибо!